# Java Number Palindrom

Tags: java, numbers, palindrome

I want to write a palindrome program which will print all palindrome numbers created by multiplying two-digit numbers (10-99)?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class PrintPalindrom {
    public int printPalindrom (int a, int b) {
        int result = a*b;
        int reverse = 0;
        if (a >= 10 && a <= 99 && b >= 10 && b <= 99) {
            while (result != 0) {
                reverse = reverse * 10;
                reverse = reverse + result % 10;
                result = result/10;
                System.out.println("palindrom is " + result);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong numbers");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How to pirnt palindrome numbers created by multiplying two-digit numbers (10-99)?

My method dosent work for now...

Comment: is it a code review ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: //Sorry for that, How to print all palindrome numbers created by multiplying two-digit numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method (`isPalindrome()`) that returns true if a number is palindrome, false otherwise. You can easily create it starting from your `printPalindrom()` method. Then, in your `main()`:

```
int from = 10;
int to = 99;
for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    for (int j = from ; j <= to; j++) {
        int mult = i*j;
        if (isPalindrome(mult))
            System.out.println(i + "x" + j + "=" + mult + " is plaindrome!");
    }
}
```

Comment: No i mus call on every palindrom create by combination of multiplaying two numbers between  10 and 99

Comment: Here`s an example: 91 * 99 = 9009 ;
44 * 58 = 2552 - so i want to print 9009 and 2552

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this code:

```
 public class PrintPalindrom {
    public int printPalindrom (int a, int b) {
        int result = a*b;
        int temp = result; 
        int reverse = 0;
        if (a >= 10 &&  a <= 99 && b >= 10 && b <= 99) {
            while (temp != 0) {
                reverse = reverse * 10;
                reverse = reverse + result % 10;
                temp = temp/10;                
            }
           if(result == reverse) {            
            return result;   
           } 
       }
      return 0;     

    }   

     int from = 10;
     int to = 99;
     for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
         for (int j = i + 1 ; j <= to; j++) {
              int result = printPalindrom(i, j);
              if(result > 0) {
                 System.out.println(result + ",");
             }              
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, using a stack if allowed to check whether a product of two numbers is a palindrom or not.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PrintPalindrom {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int MIN = 10;
        final int MAX = 99;
        for (int i = MIN; i <= MAX; i++) {
            for (int j = MIN ; j <= MAX; j++) {
                new PrintPalindrom(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    public PrintPalindrom(final int a, final int b) {
        if (a >= 10 &&  a <= 99 && b >= 10 && b <= 99) {
            final String result = String.valueOf(a * b);    //Convert the product of the int to a String
            final Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

            System.out.print(a + " * " + b + " = " + result + "\t-\t");

            //Push each character from the in to a stack
            for(int n = 0; n < result.length(); n++) {
                stack.push(result.substring(n, n + 1));
            }

            //Check each character against the characters in the stack
            for(int n = 0; n < result.length(); n++) {
                if(!result.substring(n, n + 1).equals(stack.pop())) {
                    System.out.println("Not a palindrom");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("A palindrom");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Example {

    public static void main (String[]args){
        int start = 10;
        int end = 99;            
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            for (int j = i ; j <= end; j++) {
                 printPali(i,j);              
           }
        }
    }

    public static void printPali(int i, int j) {            
        if(String.valueOf(i*j).equals(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i*j)).reverse().toString()))
            System.out.println(i + " * " + j + " = " + i*j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that in this way Create `isPalindrome` function which return `true` if the number is Palindrome then check Palindrome for each multiply result in the desired range and print it if it's `true`.

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(int num){
              int rnum = 0,digit;
              int n = num;
              while(n > 0){
                    digit = n % 10;
                    n = n / 10;
                    rnum = rnum * 10  + digit;
              }
              if(rnum == num){
                  return true;
               }
               else{
                  return false;
               }
 }        
 public static void main(String[] args) {          
            int a = 10 , b = 99;
        for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){
            for(int j = i; j <= b; j++){
                 if(isPalindrome(i * j)){
                     System.out.println("Mult Palindrome: " + i * j);
                 }
            }
        }   
 }
```

note that you can put range in the inner for loop `for(int j = a; j <= b; j++)` but it will be redundant in the multiply results without benefit so it's more efficient and optimized way to put the range from `j=i` to `b`.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Javatips {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = in.nextInt();
        int reverseNumber = 0;
        int copyNumber = number;
        boolean isPalindrom = true;
        while (copyNumber>0){
            reverseNumber = 10*reverseNumber + copyNumber%10;
            copyNumber=copyNumber/10;
            if(reverseNumber==number){
                isPalindrom = true;
            } else {
                isPalindrom = false;
            }
        }
        if(isPalindrom){
            System.out.println(number + " is palindrom");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is not palindrom");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Yes, we see your code. The problem is that it is missing an explanation for how it works and how it is better than the other answers.