# creating a list of palindrome numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

I'm trying to create a `List` of palindrome numbers that made from the product of two 3-digit numbers but it is returning []. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I couldn't add the isPalindrome function initially cause stackoverflow would complain that "my post mostly code" Is there anything wrong with my isPalindrome function?

```
public class Solution {




//list of digit numbers of a number
ArrayList<Long> digits = new ArrayList<>();

//list of palindrome numbers
public ArrayList<Long> pal = new ArrayList<>();


// checks if the given number is a palindrome
boolean isPalindrome(long num) {


// creates list of digit numbers of a number
// ex. 12345 -> [5,4,3,2,1]
while(num > 0) {
  long lastdigit = num % 10;
  digits.add(lastdigit);
  num = num / 10;
}

//checks if the number is a palindrome by checking the first and last index

// when the number of digits is even
if(digits.size() % 2 == 0) {
  while(digits.size() > 0) {
    int last = digits.size() - 1;

    if (digits.get(0) == digits.get(last)) {
      digits.remove(last);
      digits.remove(0);
    }
    else {
      return false;
      }

    }
return true;

  }

// when the number of digits is odd
else  while(digits.size() > 1) {

  int last = digits.size() - 1;
  if (digits.get(0) == digits.get(last)) {
    digits.remove(last);
    digits.remove(0);
  }
  else {
    return false;
    }

  }

  return true;

}


    ArrayList<Long> findPal() {

        for (long i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
            for (long j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
                Long product = i * j;

                if (isPalindrome(product)) {
                    pal.add(product);
                }
            }
        }
        return pal;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        System.out.println(sol.isPalindrome((long)121)); //true
        System.out.println(sol.isPalindrome((long)12345)); // false
        System.out.println(sol.findPal()); //[]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `sol.isPalindrome(12321L)`?

Comment: Where is isPalindrome method?

Comment: What is **`digits`** used for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Number Palindrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043810/java-number-palindrom)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the `isPalindrome` method that you haven't shown us.

There are a couple of other problems:

1. The `pal` field should really be a local variable in the `findPal` method.  (Hint: what happens if you call `findPal()` twice?  Once you have found the bug in `isPalindrome`, try it ....)
2. The list of palindromic numbers that you create will most likely contain duplicates.   For example, if 104 x 521 is a palindromic number, then 521 x 104 will be as well.

Comment: I couldn't add the isPalindrome function initially cause stackoverflow would complain that "my post mostly code" Is there anything wrong with my isPalindrome function?

Comment: @ken24ny - Given Naresh's answer, I think that the answer must be yes.  Can I suggest that you read this:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: And actually, the problem with your `isPalindrome` method looks like it is that same mistake that you made with the `pal` field in `findPal`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

In isPalindrome() function

```
if (digits.get(0) == digits.get(last)) {
      digits.remove(last);
      digits.remove(0);
 }
 else {
    return false;
 }
```

Here in Else block you need to empty the digits list. that is the main problem that you are not emptying it.

I just use your code and just created my isPalindrome function and everything  is working fine.

Have a look at this code.

```
public class Solution {

    ArrayList<Long> digits = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Long> pal = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Long> findPal() {

        for (long i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
            for (long j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
                Long product = i * j;

                if (isPalindrome(product)) {
                    pal.add(product);
                }
            }
        }
        return pal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        System.out.println(sol.isPalindrome((long) 121)); // true
        System.out.println(sol.isPalindrome((long) 12345)); // false
        System.out.println(sol.findPal()); // []
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(Long longValue) {

        Long temp = longValue;
        String tempLong = "";
        while (temp != 0) {
            tempLong = tempLong + temp % 10 + "";
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        return Long.parseLong(tempLong) == longValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't add the isPalindrome function initially cause stackoverflow would complain that "my post mostly code" Is there anything wrong with my isPalindrome function?

Comment: in case of non palindrome, you did not empty the digits arraylist. That is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

You must have a function in which after passing the number from the loops it should seperate the numbers to a single digit and should return true if the reverse is also true

For eg:
121 - >121%10 - >1 
Then 121/10 -> 12
Similarly keep doing this till its modulus is not zero
Then multiply the highest number with (len of digit -1) like
1*100+2*10+1
If it is same then it is palindrome
I know its quite long but its the simplest thing!